# Вращение крестика

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

```css
.inner {
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
.inner:hover .btn_image {
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Для Firefox */
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Для IE */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Для Safari, Chrome, iOS */
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Для Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn_image {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  border: solid 3px red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.btn_image:before {
  content: "";
  width: 29.4px;
  height: 3.4px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.btn_image:after {
  content: "";
  width: 29.4px;
  height: 3.4px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
 <div class="btn_image"></div>
 <h3>Создать спецификацию</h3>
</div>
```

Вопрос, почему он двигается вверх и как этого избежать?
Без `absolute` никак не получится?

Comment: Не вполне понятно, о каком "движении вверх" вы говорите? О субпиксельном смещении при hoverout?

Comment: Смещение от центра практически не заметно, даже на ретина экране. А если хотите вовсе избежать такого (даже на 1px) то придеться найти идеальный крестик + поставить фиксированную высоту и ширину + настроить четко line-height (обычно в размер высоты) + отцентровать. Ну и экспериментировать. Однако, в вашем примере все более чем хорошо. PS: Safari, MacOS.

Comment: @vp_arth, да, что то смещается вверх

Comment: @PerfectoWeb, я крестик типа картинки?

Comment: Просто попробуйте не использовать дробное количество пикселей для размеров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Субпиксельные трансформации получаются из-за указанных дробных размеров в пикселях. Используйте целые:

```css
.inner {
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
.inner:hover .btn_image {
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Для Firefox */
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Для IE */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Для Safari, Chrome, iOS */
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Для Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn_image {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  border: solid 3px red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.btn_image:before {
  content: "";
  width: 29px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.btn_image:after {
  content: "";
  width: 29px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
 <div class="btn_image"></div>
 <h3>Создать спецификацию</h3>
</div>
```